# What is the best practice to keep track of an activity even after activity is finished?

Tags: android

This is the scenario I am facing:
I have an Activity (A) in which the user can download a content (with the help of an SDK). The download starts and there is an event listener which listens to events from the SDK while downloading the content (including the download progress which updates a progress bar in my activity).

Now, if the user presses the back button to explorer other activities, the state of that Activity (A) will be lost. The download, however, resumes and works perfectly fine but since the Activity (A) finishes on the back press, when the user goes back to that activity, a new instance of event listener will be created which does not have any information about the "already-downloading" content to update progress bar properly.

What is the best practice to solve this issue? So that when the user presses the back button, the event-listener does not terminate.

This is how my code looks like in Activity A:

```
private final DownloadEventListener downloadEventListener = new DownloadEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDownloadProgress(@NonNull Video video, @NonNull DownloadStatus status) {
        updateDownloadProgressBar(status.getProgress())

    } 
}
```

screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FV38o.jpg

The SDK gives download progress periodically which makes me able to update the progress bar accordingly. However, as I mentioned, if the user presses the back button to go to another activity and comes back to this activity, the event listener is gone.

Any idea how to solve this? Can I have a public event listener?

Comment: One option is to put the download on an service, then you start the service from this activity, and keep broadcasting the progress, you can get your progress from there when you resume the activity as well

Comment: Amazing! Do you have any related tutorial links as well?

Comment: Take a look on official documentation https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services?hl=en-US Understading how services work, you can easily migrate your download code to there!! happy code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what services are for. Services are the same as activities, without the UI, that can run in the background. Per the [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services):

> A Service is an application component that can perform long-running operations in the background, and it doesn't provide a user interface. Another application component can start a service, and it continues to run in the background even if the user switches to another application. Additionally, a component can bind to a service to interact with it and even perform interprocess communication (IPC). For example, a service can handle network transactions, play music, perform file I/O, or interact with a content provider, all from the background.

So while a service can run in the background while using other applications, you could also use it while running another activity.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I will dig into more. I would appreciate if you can provide some tutorial links as well :)

Comment: Just Google "Android service tutorials".